# Why Updating value from 2 lists behave differently? (one of the item in list is a single-item list)

Tags: python, list

```py
x = [1,3,6,[18]]
y = list(x)
print(y)
x[3][0] = 15

x[1] = 12
print(x)
print(y)
```

In the above code, updating `x[3][0]` in `x` is reflected in `y` (which is the list of `x`), but the update in `x[1] = 12` is not reflected in `y`

Why this is not getting updated in `y`?

Comment: Because list `y` is *shallow* copy of list `x` which means that `list(x)` doesn't recursively copy each element of `x` so element on index `3` contains reference to same list both in `x` and `y`. To create full *(deep)* copy use [`copy.deepcopy()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html#copy.deepcopy).

Comment: You might want to check something like `x is y` or just look at the output of `id(x)` and `id(y)`

Comment: Because `x[3]` and `y[3]` refer to the same list, when you update that list via `x[3][0]` the change is visible from `y[3]` too. But when you change `x[1]` you are only changing an item in `x` ... `x` and `y` are different lists

Answer (score 4):

*A picture worth thousand words.*  Here is the picture that is missing:
(let's pretend forgetting all *terminology for a moment now)

**Credits to all posts**.  *Labor (of the wording & picturing) is mine.*

First thing first, when you try to use list constructor to create y: *list(x)* or *[:]*  it just produces a *shallow copy* (ie. the outermost container is duplicated, but the copy is filled with reference to the same item (as [18] shown in picture)

So later if you update x's [18] it will update the reference point - that's why both lists see the change of *15*.  But when you update other object, it directly change the *integer* object in the container *x* but not in *y*.

***Lesson learned - Copies are shallow by Default!***  in Python.
[image: list of list]

```
# See different code example:
x  = [1,3,6,[18]]

y =  x[:]     # new list, but it's shallow copy (last item)

print(x, id(x))   # different memory
print(y, id(y))   # but same content to start with 

x[3][0] = 15      # assign new value - reflect in both x, y
x[1] = 12         # assign new value - only affect x

print(x, id(x)) 

print(y, id(y))   # last item got changed too; because sharing
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qy0U8.png

Comment: Nice one good sir.  Upvoted for the clear explanation and effort. What’s the site again for generating these images?

Comment: Pythontutor.com. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What is happening is a *shallow copy*. When you wrote `y=list(x)`, this created a reference from y to x, and not an actual copy. What you need is a *deep copy*, a copy that creates a new list(including nested lists) instead of referencing the old one. `.copy()` won't work, because nested lists are still references even though the rest of the copied list is a separate list.

Here is the code for a deep copy:

```
import copy
x=[1,3,6,[18]]
y=copy.deepcopy(x)
print(y)
x[3][0]=15
x[1]=12
print(x)
print(y)
```

Comment: *"this created a reference from y to x, and not an actual copy"* - no, it actually creates a shallow copy, just in different way.

Comment: Hi, thanks. Pls clarify this. x[3][0]=15 - this assignment is reflected y  but x[1]=12 - this assignment is not reflected in y - can you pls explain?

Comment: And try to read/reflect and understand the ealier comments from @OlvinRoght.    And you can add ```print(id(x))```   and ```print(id(y))``` too to see if the *memory address* of these 2 diff objects.

Answer (score 0):

By using `list()` you create a new reference (y) to the same addresses in memory that (x) is referring.

Element 1 in *x* and *y* is an **integer** which is **immutable**. Once you use `x[1]=12` basically you create a new object in memory for number 12 and x[1] will refer to that object. However, y[1] still refers to previous object (i.e. 3).

Element 3 in in *x* and *y* is a **list** which is **mutable**. Once, you use `x[3][0]`, it updates the same object in memory. So, both x and y reflect the change.

I hope I could convey the concept.

Comment: A correction, if I may.  The first statement is incorrect.  Using `list()` will create a *shallow copy* of the original list, with a *new* memory addresses.  However, as this is a shallow copy, (in this case) `x[3]` and `y[3]` will have the *same* memory address. This is where OP’s confusion is originating; the fact that a shallow copy has been made.

Comment: @S3DEV, you're right, but the first statement is correct too :) You just rephrased it. You create a new reference to the same memory addresses by using shallow copy.

Quote from Python.org: "A shallow copy constructs a new compound object and then (to the extent possible) inserts references into it to the objects found in the original."

https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html

Comment: “You create a new reference to the same memory addresses by using shallow copy.” Not quite.  But rather, you create a *new* object (in a new memory location), with any nested (mutable) objects inside the parent object simply being references.

Comment: Perhaps [have a read of this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72958108/6340496) to help add some context between shallow and deep copying.

Comment: Thanks for for sharing the link. I understand the concept shallow copy and deep copy. However, I don't see the point you're trying to highlight here; is it getting the terminology right or else? Since I already confirmed your comment regarding list() creating a shallow copy. 

However, to be accurate, array y (yes, you're right. it has a location on memory) will have references to memory addresses of all elements of array x (both mutable and immutable elements). I don't explain the rest as it's already in the main post.

Answer (score 0):

They do not behave differently. Changes to `x` are never reflected in `y`.

```py
x = [1,3,6,[18]]
y = list(x)
print(y) # [1,3,6,[18]]
x[3] = [15]
print(y) # [1,3,6,[18]]
```

However, changes to the 1-element list are reflected both in `x` and in `y`:

```py
z = [18]
x = [1,3,6,z]
y = list(x)
print(y) # [1,3,6,[18]]
z[0] = 15
print(y) # [1,3,6,[15]]
```

The reason why integers and lists are different, the reason why you don't see changes to integers reflected in `y` is because it's possible to make changes to a list, but it's not possible to make changes to `int`:

```py
x = [1,3,6,[18]]
y = list(x)
print(y) # [1,3,6,[18]]
3 = 12 # SyntaxError: cannot assign to literal here.
```

In python, every type is either ***mutable*** or ***immutable***. Lists are mutable; integers are immutable.