# Python Array variable assignment

Tags: python, variable-assignment, array-indexing

I am newbie to python so having difficulty understand this code behavior for scenarios listed below.

I can understand the first 3 where the output is `a=[1], b=[0]` but in the last case why is the value of b getting changed to [1] ?

```
a = [0]
b = a[:]
a = [1]
print(a,b)

a = [0]
b = a[:]
a[0] = 1
print(a,b)

a = [0]
b = a
a = [1]
print(a,b)

a = [0]
b = a
a[0] = 1
print(a,b)
```

Comment: Read https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html.

Comment: Maybe this visual presentation can help you - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73069075/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some comments that should help clarify.

```py
a = [0]    # a is a new array
b = a[:]   # b is a copy of a
a = [1]    # a is a new array
print(a,b) # [1] [0] because they are 2 different arrays

a = [0]    # a is a new array
b = a[:]   # b is a copy of a
a[0] = 1   # modify a
print(a,b) # [1] [0] because they are 2 different arrays

a = [0]    # a is a new array
b = a      # b is a reference to a (same array)
a = [1]    # a is a new array, but b is still pointing to the first array
print(a,b) # [1] [0] because they are 2 different arrays

a = [0]    # a is a new array
b = a      # b is a reference to a (same array)
a[0] = 1   # modify a, which also modifies b since they are both references to the same array
print(a,b) # [1] [1] because they are the same array
```

You should check out [this python visualizer](https://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=display) to help clarify things, since it will show you exactly what object each reference is pointing to. Paste your code in there, then click `Visualize Execution` and step through the code to visualize the differences between these 4 blocks.

Specifically in this case, pay close attention to what happens on the `b = a` lines. Both variables will point to the same underlying list.